# The easiest way to get Legendary heroes like Darkseid?

Tags: injustice-2-mobile, injustice-2

What is the easiest way to get Legendary heroes in Injustice 2 Mobile? I recently got Brainiac by getting his shards in Challenges with SIMs. Legendary hero chests are not trustworthy if I'm not wrong. I'm trying for Darkseid this time. Is there any way to get his shards (for free), or has Injustice 2 become a pay-to-play game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a year and a half in this game, but i never got a legendary character.

I had bought 2 legendary boxes, but never getting any thing real.

The only thing i managed to gather in all these time was 14 gold characters.

So yeah, legendary characters are really difficult to get. The best bet you can place is on events, where the chances of a legendary character from a box is high. Then, you need a bit of luck to get your thing.

But, if you are unwilling to pay, it's difficult to get anywhere real on this game.

That is the truth about most games nowadays.